# Remove choice for user delete from Roles which can adminster the Users

Tags: 7, users

I have a **User Role** called **Supervisor** which can create new accounts of role **Supervisor**.

The **Supervisor** can also delete other users with **supervisor** role. While deleting Other users the Supervisor gets the 4 choices that Drupal comes standard with:-

[image]

However, I want to present the **Supervisor** only the first option:-
 ***Disable the account and keep its content***
and other options to be hidden or disabled by default.

I'd be very thankful for any hints how to achieve that... I'm already using **Role Delegation module** and have been trying different settings, looks like its not possible via that module.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating a custom module and try using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
  switch ($form_id)  {
    case 'user-multiple-cancel-confirm':
        // ALTER STUFF.. user dsm($form) to show available fields.
        break;
   }
}
```

Using

```
global $user; 
$roles = $user->roles; // Array with user assigned roles
```

you can check the array for the Supervisor role.

Comment: just a minor issue... $form_id will only return the form's title.  $form will return the fields.

Comment: You're totally right! I've updated the answer.